# I'm trying to auto login in npm using bash script, but I don't know how ti input username and password when requested. is it possible?

Tags: node.js, bash, authentication, npm

I'm writing a bash script to install nodejs and setup a private npm registry, everything is ok until i get here:

## setting npm registry:

npm set registry http://privateip:4873

npm login --registry=http://privateip:4873/

## here I'm asked for user and password and I don't know how to input, is it possible in bash scripting?

thanks

Comment: a simple google search can give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Tokens instead of user and password.

Take a look [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules)